# TensorFlow custom loss ValueError: "No gradients provided for any variable: [....'Layers'....]"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, sequence, loss-function, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to use the inbuilt TensorFlow function as a loss function to compile my model. Is it because of the changing from numpy array to tensor, or is it something about the function.
My code:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, Flatten, LSTM, TimeDistributed, Bidirectional,RepeatVector, SimpleRNN, GRU
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import tensorflow as tf
import math


def edit_dist(y_pred, y_true):
  dist = tf.edit_distance(tf.sparse.from_dense([y_pred]), tf.sparse.from_dense([y_true]), normalize=False)
  return dist

def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(200,  input_shape=(1,x_train.shape[2]))))
    model.add(RepeatVector(y_train.shape[1]))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences = True)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences = True)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(y_train.shape[2], activation='softmax')))
    model.compile(loss=edit_dist, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])  
    return model


ips = read_csv('Data (1).csv', dtype=float)
fullset = np.array(ips)
fullset=fullset[2:,:]

xy = fullset[np.where(fullset[:,0]==518)]
np.random.shuffle(xy)

x = xy[:,4:76]
y_1 = xy[:,76:]
x=x/x.max(axis=0)

k=int(np.around(0.85*x.shape[0]))
l=int(np.around(0.85*x.shape[0]))
x_train = x[0:l,:]
y_train = y_1[0:l,:]
x_val = x[l+1:,:]
y_val = y_1[l+1:,:]
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_val = to_categorical(y_val)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],1, x_train.shape[1]))
x_val = np.reshape(x_val, (x_val.shape[0],1, x_val.shape[1]))

model = baseline_model()
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=300, batch_size = 128, verbose=1,validation_data=(x_val, 
y_val))

plt.plot(hist.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:757 train_step
        self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:498 minimize
        return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:598 apply_gradients
        grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py:79 filter_empty_gradients
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['bidirectional_27/forward_lstm_27/lstm_cell_82/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_27/forward_lstm_27/lstm_cell_82/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_27/forward_lstm_27/lstm_cell_82/bias:0', 'bidirectional_27/backward_lstm_27/lstm_cell_83/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_27/backward_lstm_27/lstm_cell_83/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_27/backward_lstm_27/lstm_cell_83/bias:0', 'bidirectional_28/forward_lstm_28/lstm_cell_85/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_28/forward_lstm_28/lstm_cell_85/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_28/forward_lstm_28/lstm_cell_85/bias:0', 'bidirectional_28/backward_lstm_28/lstm_cell_86/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_28/backward_lstm_28/lstm_cell_86/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_28/backward_lstm_28/lstm_cell_86/bias:0', 'bidirectional_29/forward_lstm_29/lstm_cell_88/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_29/forward_lstm_29/lstm_cell_88/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_29/forward_lstm_29/lstm_cell_88/bias:0', 'bidirectional_29/backward_lstm_29/lstm_cell_89/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_29/backward_lstm_29/lstm_cell_89/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_29/backward_lstm_29/lstm_cell_89/bias:0', 'time_distributed_9/kernel:0', 'time_distributed_9/bias:0'].
```

Also, should i make my own edit distance function to use as loss function rather than using the inbuilt one for faster operation?

Answer (score 0):

The edit distance is not differentiable, so you cannot use it as a loss function. You can only use differentiable functions as loss.